# Why isn't the dispenser giving me spectrespecs?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I am in Year 6: Spectrespecs (PS3 version) and have got the spectrespecs at Hogsmeade Station. When following Nick to the gate I need another pair of spectrespecs from the mailbox but I can only get a cartoon out of it and no spectrespecs. How do I get the spectrespecs so I can open the gate?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you got the ability and the gold brick after leaving the train station?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned following Nick, I infer you are playing the *To the Next Mission - Young Dumbledore, Draught of Living Death* level.

If you have unlocked the gold brick (as you stated you did) then you should have no issue retrieving the pair of spectrespecs to unlock the gate.  **Generally** if you don't receive an item from a box it's because you have the item activated already, it's always worth double checking your spell wheel and see if you have the option available.

[The area in question is shown here around 1:40.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiuursunK1Y)

Comment: Can you check that link?  There appears to be a copy and paste error.

Comment: For some reason the word wrap introduced a break in the link, possibly related to cutting and pasting ... from the edit screen the full link was there.  I've put in a shorter, youtube link. Thanks!